# React Native - Rendering Issues with sqlite database

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, sqlite

I am suffering from problems with using sqlite in React Native.
If I click a button on the searchscreen, the screen changes. I tried to load and display data in a new screen(which is Bookmark), but it doesn't work properly.
It renders nothing in the beginning. When I click save button, it shows data. But I want to render immediately.

this is my code:

```
/*This is SearchScreen.js*/
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import Search from "./mode/Search";
import Bookmark from "./mode/Bookmark";
import Expiration from "./mode/Expiration";

const componentMap = {
    Search,
    Expiration,
    Bookmark,
};

function renderText(mode){
    switch(mode){
        case 'Expiration':
            return '유통기한';
        case 'Bookmark':
            return '즐겨찾기';
        default: 
            return '';
    }
}

const SearchScreen = () => {
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('Search');

    const renderScreen = () => {
        const Component = componentMap[mode];
        return <Component/>;
    };
    
    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1,}}>
            <SearchBar searchText={searchText} setSearchText={setSearchText} onSubmit={()=>{setMode('Search')}}/>

            <Text style={styles.recommendText} >레시피 추천 </Text>
            <View style={styles.buttonview}>
                {Object.keys(componentMap).map(type => (type!=='Search'?
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        key={type}
                        style={[
                            styles.switch,
                            {
                                backgroundColor:
                                    mode === type ? '#e1615b' : '#EFEFEF',
                            },
                        ]}
                        onPress={() => setMode(type)}
                    >
                        <Text style={{color: mode===type? 'white': '#1A1A1A'}}>{renderText(type)}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    : null
                ))}
            </View>
            {renderScreen()}            
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button:{
        margin: 5,
        padding: 5
    },
    recommendText: { marginTop: 15, marginLeft: 25, marginBottom: 5, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "700" },
    buttonview: { flexDirection: "row", paddingLeft: 18, margin: 5 },
    switch: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginVertical: 2,
        marginHorizontal: 2,
        paddingVertical: 8,
        paddingHorizontal: 12,
        borderRadius: 6
    },
})

export default SearchScreen;
```

```
/*This is Bookmark.js*/
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import SQLite from "react-native-sqlite-storage";
import Thumbnail from "../Thumbnail";

var db = SQLite.openDatabase({ name: 'recipe.db', createFromLocation:"~www/recipe.db"});
var recipe_db = SQLite.openDatabase({ name: 'db.sqlite', createFromLocation:"~www/db.sqlite"});

const Bookmark = () => {
    //const isFocused = useIsFocused()
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const [ingList, setIngList] = useState([]);
    const [recipeList, setRecipeList] = useState({
        name: [],
        id: []
    });
    const [thumbnailList, setthumbnailList] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        getbookmark();
        getrecipe();
    }, [])
    useEffect(() => {
        searchRecipe();
    },[]);

    const getbookmark = () => {
        db.transaction((tx) => {
          tx.executeSql(
            'SELECT name FROM ingredients WHERE bookmark=1',
            [],
            (tx, results) => {
              var bookmarks = [];
              for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
                 bookmarks.push(results.rows.item(i).name);
              }
              setIngList(bookmarks);
            }
          );
        });
      }

    const getrecipe = () => {
        let query = '...**query';
        for (let i = 0; i < ingList.length; ++i) {
            query = query + " trim(A.ingredient_name) = " + "\'" + ingList[i].trim() + "\'";
            if (i != ingList.length - 1) {
                query = query + " OR";
            }
        }
        query = query + "**query";
        console.log('query: ', query)

        recipe_db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
                query,
                [],
                (tx, results) => {
                    var name = [];
                    var id = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < (results.rows.length > 5 ? 5 : results.rows.length); ++i) {
                        name.push(results.rows.item(i).name);
                        id.push(results.rows.item(i).recipe_id);
                        console.log(results.rows.item(i))
                    }
                    setRecipeList({ name: name, id: id })
                }
            );
        });
    }

    
    const searchRecipe = () => {  
        getThumbnail(recipeList)
    }

    
    
    const maxResults = 1;
    
    function getThumbnail(Array){
        _getThumbnail(Array.name)
    }
    
    async function _getThumbnail(query) {
        let videoList = [];
        for (const q of query) {
            console.log('q is', q)
        const optionParams = {
            q: q,
            part: "snippet",
            key: YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
            type: "video",
            maxResults: maxResults,
            regionCode: "KR",
            videoDuration: "short"
        };
        optionParams.q = encodeURI(optionParams.q);

        var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?";
        for (var option in optionParams) {
            url += option + "=" + optionParams[option] + "&";
        }

        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
        };
        await fetch(url, options)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((resData) => {
                for (var i = 0; i < maxResults; i++) {
                    if (resData['items'][i]) {
                        const vId = resData['items'][i]['id']['videoId'];
                        const imguri = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + vId + '/hqdefault.jpg';
                        const name = q;
                        videoList.push({ vId, imguri, name });
                    }
                }
                console.log('videolist: ',videoList)
                setthumbnailList(videoList)        
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
            .finally(()=>{
            }
            )
        }
        
        setIsLoading(false)
    }
    

    return (
        <>
            <Text>Bookmark</Text>
            <ScrollView>
                {(!isLoading) ?
                    thumbnailList.map((thumbnail, index) => {
                        return (<Thumbnail key={index} vId={thumbnail.vId} title={thumbnail.name} rId={recipeList[index]} imguri={thumbnail.imguri} />)
                    })

                    : <Text>Loading</Text>
                }
            </ScrollView>
        </>
    )
}

export default Bookmark;
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `isLoading`

```
 <ScrollView>
   {(thumbnailList.length > 0) 
    ? thumbnailList.map((thumbnail, index) => {
       return (<Thumbnail key={index} vId={thumbnail.vId} title=. 
     {thumbnail.name} rId={recipeList[index]} imguri={thumbnail.imguri} 
      />)})
    : <Text>Loading</Text>
   }
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @yoojin, Did this solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write setLoading(false) below the setTumbnail() when fetch successfull.

```
.then((resData) => {
                for (var i = 0; i < maxResults; i++) {
                    if (resData['items'][i]) {
                        const vId = resData['items'][i]['id']['videoId'];
                        const imguri = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + vId + '/hqdefault.jpg';
                        const name = q;
                        videoList.push({ vId, imguri, name });
                    }
                }
                console.log('videolist: ',videoList)
                setthumbnailList(videoList)  
                setLoading(false)// write it here
  
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                setLoading(false)// write it here
            })
```